# AJAX response not changing current HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

My problem is this. I have project in Laravel have made AJAX call for like button. Data base gets updated and all but on success jQuery  only changes first matching id not the one I am clicking on. My code below.

```
$(function(){
    $('#likeForm').submit(function(e){
        var success = "<span style='color: #286090'><span class='fa fa-heart'></span><span> Liked</span>";
        e.preventDefault();
        var user = $('input[name="user_id"]').val();
        var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'like-post',
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                '_token': token, 
                'user': user 
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function() {
                $('#likeButton').replaceWith(success);
            },
            error: function() {}
        })
    })
});
```

```html
<form id="likeForm" >
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}" >
    <a class="likeBtn" id="likeButton" onclick="$('#likeForm').submit()"><span>
    <span class="fa fa-heart"></span> Like</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
</form>
```

Comment: `jQuery only changes first matching id` That's your problem - you cannot have multiple `id` attributes in the DOM. They *must* be unique. Change them to classes

Comment: I understand that but, how to change it to class that on success it will replace correct HTML.

Comment: Did you try with html rather then using replaceWith

Comment: Change the selector if you want to select element by the class.

`$('.likeBtn').replaceWith(success);`

Comment: @Joe I added an answer with an example for you

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments said, you can only have uniques ids in your html code.

To update the form the user clicked on, you need to use `this`:

```
$(function(){
    $('.likeForm').submit(function(e){
        var self = this;
        var success = "<span style='color: #286090'><span class='fa fa-heart'></span><span> Liked</span>";
        e.preventDefault();
        var user = $('input[name="user_id"]').val();
        var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'like-post',
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                '_token': token, 
                'user': user 
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function() {
                $(self).find('.likeButton').replaceWith(success);
            },
            error: function() {}
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: This will call `replaceWith()` on the `form`, not the `a` element.

Comment: He seems here to want to replace entirely his form with a span

Comment: Not sure why you have that idea? His original code is targetting only the `#likeButton` element, which is the `a`

Comment: Ho ok you are right, I didn't see that, sorry, I edited my response

Comment: It works once ant on first class in dom not current.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, an ID is used for a unique element. If you have more that 2 ID in your HTML then you are wrong. jQuery will select the first ID he founds. You should use classes instead, or data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery only changes first matching id

That's your problem - you cannot have multiple `id` attributes in the DOM. They *must* be unique. Change them to classes. You will also need to traverse the DOM using the reference of the element which raised the event to find the elements you need to change. Try this:

```
<form class="likeForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" class="token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
    <button class="likeBtn>
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span> 
        Like
    </button>
</form>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('.likeForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url:'like-post',
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                _token: $form.find('.token'),
                user: $form.find('.user_id') 
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function() {
                $form.find('.likeBtn').replaceWith('<span style="color: #286090"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span><span> Liked</span>');
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Note that I changed the `a` with the `onclick` attribute to a `button`. This means the `form` element will be automatically submit on click of that button without any JS interference. You can then simply style the button as you need using CSS.

Comment: It dons't work. I am genering like forms with foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
success: function() {
                $('#likeButton').replaceWith(success);
            },
```

try

```
success: function() {
                $(this).replaceWith(success);
            },
```

Comment: This will call `replaceWith()` on the `form`, not the `a` element.

Comment: i tried.. it worked for me... try and give this a shot